# Cannot convert arg (type string) to type Lambo

Tags: go

in golang I tried this, but it gives me error

```
type Car interface{
    Drive()
    Stop()
}

type Lambo struct{
    Lambomodel string
}

func NewModel(arg string) Car{
    return Lambo(arg)
}
```

why do I get

> Cannot convert arg (type string) to type Lambo

this error

Answer (score 1):

```
    return Lambo(arg)
```

Is not struct initialization, but type conversion of `arg` into the type `Lambo`.

The syntax you looking for is:

```
    return Lambo{arg}
```

But Lambo still needs to implement `Drive` and `Stop` to conform to the interface.

Answer (score 0):

I just forgot that it needs {} instead of (). And therefor it is inter